# Why am I having this Javascript ".querySelectorAll" issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, button, selector, queryselector

I am following a tutorial to create a portfolio website. I have followed the tutorial exactly with no errors (Yes, I am using a tutorial, I have not built anything on my own yet, but I'm hopefully getting there). I am getting an error message on my live server that the tutorial is not getting and I am not sure how to fix it. Any opinions would be very helpful!

**Here is the error message I am receiving**:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn48P.png)

**And here is the code I am using (The errors are on lines 17,18, and 38)**:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.control');
const allSections = document.querySelectorAll('.main-content');


function PageTransitions(){
    //Button click active class
    for(let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++){
        sectBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
            let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
            currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn', '');
            this.className += ' active-btn';
        })
    }

    //Sections Active class
17    ***allSections.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
18        const id = e.target.dataset.id;*** 
        if(id){
            //remove selected from the other btns
            sectBtns.forEach((btn) =>{
                btn.classList.remove('active');
            })
            e.target.classList.add('active');

            //hide other sections
            sections.forEach((section)=>{
                section.classList.remove('active');
            })

            const element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.classList.add('active');
        }
    })
}

38  **PageTransitions()**;
```

I have tried going back through my video and seeing if I had everything exactly the way the video has it and I do. The goal was for a specific section to appear when a different icon on the website is clicked. For example, if I clicked the "home" icon, a green background would appear, but when I clicked the "contact" icon, a red background would appear, etc...

Unfortunately, the error message is still coming up and it's not allowing the changes to take place and I am not sure how to rectify this issue if I am copying the exact code the tutorial is showing me and it is working on the video but not on my end.

Any opinions are helpful, thank you for your time!

Comment: You can't add markdown in a code block FYI

Comment: Could you please post any output from the console that may be helpful?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You do not need to advertise you're new to coding in huge letters in the title. We're more than happy to help, but stay focused on your *technical problem*.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of elements. You need to loop over that collection (however, event propagation might be probably a better idea instead).

Comment: @Designly At the top

Comment: @MichaelM. you got it. Post an answer?

Comment: @Designly Nope, its a dupe.

Comment: Use [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to remove the class....

Comment: Check out the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.